# Why is it saying not defined?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.4

first off im very new to programing Python 3.4.3, im trying to call 5 entrys and put them into and array and display that, but im stuck at GPA1 not defined, but it is defined in for the entry app

```
import sys
from tkinter import * 

def save_data(): 

    fileD.write("GPA1:\n")
    fileD.write("%s\n" % GPA1.get())
    fileD.write("GPA2:\n")
    fileD.write("%s\n" % GPA2.get())
    fileD.write("GPA3:\n") 
    fileD.write("%s\n" % GPA3.get("1.0", END))

    app = Tk() 
    app.title('Student Grade Report')

    gpa1=str(GPA1.get())
    gp1=float(gpa1)
    gpa2=str(GPA2.get())
    gp2=float(gpa2)
    gpa3=str(GPA3.get())
    gp3=float(gpa3)
    gpa4=str(GPA4.get())
    gp4=float(gpa4)
    gpa5=str(GPA5.get())
    gp5=float(gpa5)
    gpas=gp1+gp2+gp3+gp4+gp5
    avg=gpas/5
    def DisplayMsg():
        DL=str("Dean's list")
        AP=str("Academic Probation")
        note=("No Message")
        if (avg>3.5):
        note=DL
    else:
        if (avg<2.0):
            note=AP
    return str(note)




    classi = StringVar() 
    classi.set(None)


    Label(app, text = "Classification:").pack()
    Classification = StringVar() 
    Classification.set(None)
    Radiobutton(app, variable = classi, text = "freshman", value = "freshman").pack()
    Radiobutton(app, variable = classi, text = "sophmore", value = "sophmore").pack()
    Radiobutton(app, variable = classi, text = "junior", value = "junior").pack()
    Radiobutton(app, variable = classi, text = "senior", value = "senior").pack()

    Label(app, text = "GPA1:").pack()
    GPA1= StringVar()
    GPA1.set(None)
    GPA1= Entry(app,textvariable=Gpa1).pack() 
    Label(app, text = "GPA2:").pack()
    GPA2= StringVar()
    GPA2.set(None)
    GPA2 = Entry(app) 
    Label(app, text = "GPA3:").pack()
    GPA3= StringVar()
    GPA3.set(None)
    GPA3= Entry(app)
    Label(app, text = "GPA4:").pack()
    GPA4= StringVar()
    GPA4.set(None)
    GPA4= Entry(app)
    Label(app, text = "GPA5:").pack()
    GPA5= StringVar()
    GPA5.set(None)
    GPA5= Entry(app)


    Button(app, text= "Message", command = DisplayMsg).pack()

    Button(app, text = "Save", command = save_data).pack() 

    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is your indentation messed up? All the code after `return str(note)` should not be indented, because then it's part of the function.

Comment: Please paste the actual exception and traceback, rather than just a vague description of it.

Answer (score 0):

The program published above does have some problems with indentation, but I suspect that this happened when inserting into the editor.

Also, I suspect your error says Gpa1 undefined, not GPA1. This is because you assign a text variable to the Entry which is not initialized yet (i.e. it does not exist).

The way you pack() the widgets, make them appear vertically. If you want them in a spreadsheet like table, you have to use a packer such as .grid(), and specify the column and row where you want the widget to appear.

Here's the code, slightly cleaned up (Note that I had to use Tkinter to find the module - not tkinter):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from Tkinter import * 

def save_data(): 

    fileD.write("GPA1:\n")
    fileD.write("%s\n" % GPA1.get())
    fileD.write("GPA2:\n")
    fileD.write("%s\n" % GPA2.get())
    fileD.write("GPA3:\n") 
    fileD.write("%s\n" % GPA3.get("1.0", END))

    app = Tk() 
    app.title('Student Grade Report')

    gpa1=str(GPA1.get())
    gp1=float(gpa1)
    gpa2=str(GPA2.get())
    gp2=float(gpa2)
    gpa3=str(GPA3.get())
    gp3=float(gpa3)
    gpa4=str(GPA4.get())
    gp4=float(gpa4)
    gpa5=str(GPA5.get())
    gp5=float(gpa5)
    gpas=gp1+gp2+gp3+gp4+gp5
    avg=gpas/5

def DisplayMsg():
    DL=str("Dean's list")
    AP=str("Academic Probation")
    note=("No Message")

    if (avg>3.5):
        note=DL
    elif (avg<2.0):
            note=AP

    return str(note)



def main():
    app = Tk()
    app.title('Student Grade Report')

    classi = StringVar() 
    classi.set(None)

    Label(app, text = "Classification:").pack()
    Classification = StringVar() 
    Classification.set(None)
    Radiobutton(app, variable = classi, text = "freshman", value = "freshman").pack()
    Radiobutton(app, variable = classi, text = "sophmore", value = "sophmore").pack()
    Radiobutton(app, variable = classi, text = "junior", value = "junior").pack()
    Radiobutton(app, variable = classi, text = "senior", value = "senior").pack()

    Gpa1 = None

    Label(app, text = "GPA1:").pack()
    GPA1= StringVar()
    GPA1.set(None)
    GPA1= Entry(app,textvariable = Gpa1).pack()

    Label(app, text = "GPA2:").pack()
    GPA2= StringVar()
    GPA2.set(None)
    GPA2 = Entry(app) 
    Label(app, text = "GPA3:").pack()

    GPA3= StringVar()
    GPA3.set(None)
    GPA3= Entry(app)
    Label(app, text = "GPA4:").pack()
    GPA4= StringVar()
    GPA4.set(None)
    GPA4= Entry(app)
    Label(app, text = "GPA5:").pack()
    GPA5= StringVar()
    GPA5.set(None)
    GPA5= Entry(app)


    Button(app, text= "Message", command = DisplayMsg).pack()

    Button(app, text = "Save", command = save_data).pack() 

    app.mainloop() 

main()
```

NOTE: Sorry! I added a NOTE to the original post, instead of my answer. Here's the correct note: You are not done yet! There are still issues to be resolved. Eg. The fileD.write won't work if you don't open the file first.

Comment: yes there are other things that i have to do like save all the data to a specific .txt document but i have not added that yet

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jace/Documents/Test 4.py", line 18, in <module>
    gpa1=str(GPA1.get())
NameError: name 'GPA1' is not defined                                                                               thats the error i am getting, do i need to add all these to a function and then call them once the entry has been input, @jcoppens

Comment: Try to load the version of the program I uploaded. If you made errors with the indentation, then that could cause the variable GPA1 (and GPA2...) to be invisible to the functions.  The lines from `classi = StringVar()` on should be either at the left margin (as Barmar noted), or in a function (like I did). Else they are considered part of the `save_data` function and that would cause the 'undefined' error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix all the problems described in [jcoppens' very thorough answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29996465/908494), but the actual problem you're asking about is *another* one, that you *also* need to fix. (I'm assuming that your actual indentation and structure looks like what he's guessed in his answer. If this doesn't apply to your actual code… well, it applies to the code in his answer, which your code will hopefully be a lot like once you fix all the other problems.)

---

Inside `save_data`, you do this:

```
fileD.write("%s\n" % GPA1.get())
```

But there's no global variable named `GPA1`, and no local variable inside that function named `GPA1`.

There *is* a local variable inside `main` with that name, but that doesn't help; the whole point of local variables is that they're local—the only live inside one function.

You could fix this by making `GPA1` global, by just adding `global GPA1` to the top of your `main` function. This is the quickest solution, but usually not the best.

A better solution is to create a `class`, and make `GPA1` an attribute of that class. Whichever Tkinter docs or tutorial you're using will probably have lots of good examples of this.

You could also change `save_data` to take `GPA1` as a parameter, and then use `functools.partial(save_data, GPA1)` instead of just `save_data`, as a callback.

Or you could put all of these functions inside another function and make `GPA1` a `nonlocal` variable instead of a `global` one. (I wouldn't recommend this, just including it for completeness…)

Of course whatever you do, you need to do the same for `GPA2` or you'll just get the same error again two lines later.

---

Needless to say, there's no guarantee this is the last bug in your program.